# SIP simulation programs at home

Tags: network-programming, simulation, sip

We have Cisco's packet tracer for CCNA course, which helps us to understand the real-time scenario of networking between several devices which can be installed at home PC, office PC, anywhere.

Likewise, do we have any such open source for Session Initiation Protocol. I know that there are Sipp, MAPS for testing when you have real SIP phones next to you. But do we have software(s) which would help us without SIP phones like in a real-time environment ? Google didn't help me, can you guys ?

Answer (score 1):

You can run smoothing such as Asterix on a virtual machine in conjunction with a SIP client (such as Zoiper).  I am not sure if you will be able to do this with Packet Tracer however. You may want to use GNS3 for your network simulation.  I would also suggest running Wireshark in between you SIP client and your chosen SIP software solution in order to see what the SIP traffic is actually doing within the sessions.  Hope this helps.

For testing out SIP related technology I would suggest using one of the software SIP solutions provided below:

  Asterisk
  Cipango SipServlets 1.1 application server
  Elastix
  FreeSWITCH
  FreePBX
  GNU SIP Witch
  Kamailio, formerly OpenSER[1]
  Mobicents Platform (JSLEE[2] 1.0 compliant and SIP Servlets 1.1 compliant application server)
  Mysipswitch
  OpenSIPS, fork of OpenSER
  SailFin
  SIP Express Router (SER)
  Enterprise Communications System sipXecs
  Yate
  YXA, based on Erlang

Source: [List of SIP Software from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_software)